# Preparing a power point presentation with R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, image-size

I can't adjust the position and size of the image in a powerpoint presentation with R markdown?

I am preparing a power point presentation with R markdown. I have attached a reference pptx file because I will make the presentation vertically. However, I am having trouble making a cover page. Can I create a cover photo like the attached image?

[image]